# Trying to isolate URL suffix's from list of href tags

Tags: python, list, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I'm currently working on a simple web crawling program that will crawl the SCP wiki to find links to other articles in each article. So far I have been able to get a list of href tags that go to other articles, but can't navigate to them since the URL I need is embedded in the tag:

```
[ <a href="/scp-1512">SCP-1512</a>, 
<a href="/scp-2756">SCP-2756</a>, 
<a href="/scp-002">SCP-002</a>, 
<a href="/scp-004">SCP-004</a> ]
```

**Is there any way I would be able to isolate the "/scp-xxxx" from each item in the list so I can append it to the parent URL?**

The code used to get the list looks like this:

```
import requests
import lxml
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

def searchSCP(x):
    url = str(SCoutP(x))
    c = requests.get(url)
    crawl = BeautifulSoup(c.content, 'lxml')

    #Searches HTML for text containing "SCP-" and href tags containing "scp-"
    ref = crawl.find_all(text=re.compile("SCP-"), href=re.compile("scp-",))

    param = "SCP-" + str(SkateP(x)) #SkateP takes int and inserts an appropriate number of 0's.
    for i in ref: #Below function is for sorting out references to the article being searched
        if str(param) in i:
            ref.remove(i)

    if ref != []:
         print(ref)
```

The main idea I've tried to use is finding every item that contains items in quotations, but obviously that just returned the same list. What I want to be able to do is select a specific item in the list and take out ONLY the "scp-xxxx" part or, alternatively, change the initial code to only extract the href content in quotations to the list.

Comment: You can do `find_all` to fetch all of the `"a"` tags, then pull the `href` attribute from that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way I would be able to isolate the "/scp-xxxx" from each item in the list so I can append it to the parent URL?

If I understand correctly, you want to extract the `href` attribute - for that, you can use [`i.get('href')`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#attributes) (or probably even just `i['href']`).

---

With [`.select`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) and [list comprehension](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp), you won't even need regex to filter the results:

```py
[a.get('href') for a in crawl.select('*[href*="scp-"]') if 'SCP-' in a.get_text()]
```

would return

```py
['/scp-1512', '/scp-2756', '/scp-002', '/scp-004']
```

---

If you want the parent url attached:

```py
root_url = 'https://PARENT-URL.com' ## replace with the actual parent url

scpLinks = [root_url + l for l, t in list(set([
    (a.get('href'), a.get_text()) for a in crawl.select('*[href*="scp-"]')
])) if 'SCP-' in t]
```

`scpLinks` should return

```py
['https://PARENT-URL.com/scp-004', 'https://PARENT-URL.com/scp-002', 'https://PARENT-URL.com/scp-1512', 'https://PARENT-URL.com/scp-2756']
```

---

If you want to filter out `param`, add `str(param) not in t` to the filter:

```py
scpLinks = [root_url + l for l, t in list(set([
    (a.get('href'), a.get_text()) for a in crawl.select('*[href*="scp-"]')
])) if 'SCP-' in t and str(param) not in t]
```

if `str(param)` was `'SCP-002'`, then `scpLinks` would be

```py
['https://PARENT-URL.com/scp-004', 'https://PARENT-URL.com/scp-1512', 'https://PARENT-URL.com/scp-2756']
```

Comment: Thanks for the assistance, got it to work without the `list(set` and am curious what you used them for.

Comment: @MrPigsWorth just to get a unique list - I wasn't sure if some links are repeated or not [actually, just `set(...` is enough in this context, but it's become a habit to convert the set back to a list]